# "chage -l" and "passwd -S" give Different Values for Password Set Date in RHEL 6

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, passwd

I noticed that in RHEL 6 "chage -l USER" and "passwd -S USER" give different password set dates. Curious to know why. Here is what I see:

```
[root@sci-fi ~]# chage -l jedi
Last password change                    : Jun 21, 2015
Password expires                    : never
Password inactive                   : never
Account expires                     : never
Minimum number of days between password change      : 0
Maximum number of days between password change      : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 7

[root@sci-fi ~]# passwd -S jedi
jedi PS 2015-06-20 0 99999 7 -1 (Password set, SHA512 crypt.)
```

When I match the results to what is seen in /etc/shadow for the new account, I get 6/20/2015 as **passwd** shows. Here is the epoch converted in to a date value for the user jedi:

```
[root@sci-fi ~]# date -d@"$(echo "$(awk -F ":" '/jedi/ {print $3}' /etc/shadow)*86400"|bc)"
Sat Jun 20 20:00:00 EDT 2015
```

So, which is correct?

**Although the correct answer has already been given below. I did some more digging and have been able to reasonably prove that the answer is correct.
This link was very helpful:

https://serverfault.com/questions/220633/calculate-days-since-1-1-1970

1. When a password is set via the passwd command, /etc/shadow will record 
   the number of days since the epoch (1/1/1970) using the time in UTC

I did a test to prove this. I set a new password on the jedi account. 
The current days since the epoch is 16823, as calculated below

```
[root@sci-fi ~]# echo $(($(date --utc --date "$1" +%s)/86400))
16823
```

The file /etc/shadow agrees with this (so this is a fact):

```
[root@sci-fi ~]# awk -F ":" '/jedi/ {print $3}' /etc/shadow
16823
```

2. The chage program uses the last password change as reported in the /etc/shadow file to report the last change date:

The strace tool shows me that the file /etc/shadow is accessed by chage. Yes a few other files are read by chage, but only the shadow file has the days since the epoch when the password was last set

```
[root@sci-fi ~]# strace chage -l jedi 2>&1 | grep etc
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
access("/etc/shadow", F_OK)             = 0
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY)           = 4
open("/etc/shadow", O_RDONLY)           = 5
open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY)        = 6
```

Because of this, it is no surprise that the chage program reports that the
password was last changed on Jan. 23rd

```
[root@sci-fi ~]# chage -l jedi | head -1
Last password change                    : Jan 23, 2016
```

3. The passwd command is a little different and not so clear cut.

Using strace, it looks like the passwd command also pulls out the
last password change from /etc/shadow.

```
[root@sci-fi ~]# strace passwd -S jedi 2>&1 | grep etc
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY)    = 4
read(4, "#\n# /etc/nsswitch.conf\n#\n# An ex"..., 4096) = 1688
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 4
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/etc/libuser.conf", O_RDONLY)     = 4
open("/etc/login.defs", O_RDONLY)       = 4
open("/etc/default/useradd", O_RDONLY)  = 4
stat("/etc/shadow", {st_mode=S_IFREG, st_size=1295, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY)           = 4
open("/etc/shadow", O_RDONLY)           = 4
open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY)        = 4
```

4. The "passwd -S" output seems to report the last password change 
   time as recorded in /etc/shadow with respect to the locale of 
   the system. Here is my locale and the output of "passwd -S":

   [root@sci-fi ~]# ls -l /etc/localtime
   lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 36 Jan 23 17:59 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York

   [root@sci-fi ~]# passwd -S jedi
   jedi PS 2016-01-22 0 99999 7 -1 (Password set, SHA512 crypt.)

To test my theory. I changed the zone to London (5 hours ahead):

```
[root@sci-fi ~]# ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 33 Jan 24 00:33 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London

[root@sci-fi ~]# passwd -S jedi
jedi PS 2016-01-23 0 99999 7 -1 (Password set, SHA512 crypt.)
```

The output of the "passwd -S" command now matches what is seen by "chage -l".

If I instead change the time zone to mountain standard (MST), I get the same value as I did using the EST time zone:

```
[root@sci-fi ~]# ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 34 Jan 23 17:49 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Denver

[root@sci-fi ~]# passwd -S jedi
jedi PS 2016-01-22 0 99999 7 -1 (Password set, SHA512 crypt.)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably both:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23193/etc-shadow-date-of-last-password-change-utc-or-local-time

If you add the "-u" flag to date in your calculation, I expect it would return the 21st of June also.

Comment: Yes, using -u with date did give me the UTC time which resulted in 6/21/2015. So, the output of "chage -l" reports the UTC time for the last password change, whereas the output of "passwd -S" returns the time using the local time as seen by the server. Thanks.